# Lodash "uniqBy" conditions for reducing duplicated array values

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting, lodash

So I have a collection of array with this format.

```
var innitialArray = [
[0:"Hello", 1:"World", 3: "Wow", 4:"I WANT MORE"],
[0:"Hello", 1:"World", 3: "Wow", 4:"MORE I WANT"],
[0:"Meow", 1:"World", 3: "Wow", 4:"MORE I WANT"],
[0:"Meow", 1:"World", 3: "Wow", 4:"I WANT MORE"]
];
```

I've tried to use the loadash _.uniqBy method by using this code.

```
let uniq_ws_data = _.uniqBy(ws_data_initial, function (e) {
return e[0];
});
```

What i get with the code above is this array :

```
var uniq_ws_data = [
[0:"Hello", 1:"World", 3: "Wow", 4:"I WANT MORE"],
[0:"Meow", 1:"World", 3: "Wow", 4:"I WANT MORE"],
];
```

But my expected is result is should be this :

```
var uniq_ws_data = [
[0:"Hello", 1:"World", 3: "Wow", 4:"I WANT MORE"],
[0:"Meow", 1:"World", 3: "Wow", 4:"MORE I WANT"],
];
```

Also tried to change `return e[0] to e[4]` but i got the this instead :

```
var uniq_ws_data = [
[0:"Hello", 1:"World", 3: "Wow", 4:"I WANT MORE"],
[0:"Hello", 1:"World", 3: "Wow", 4:"MORE I WANT"],
];
```

Is there a way to achieve my expected result?

Code used :

```
let uniq_ws_data = _.uniqBy(ws_data_initial, function (e) {
return e[0];
});
```

Expected result :

```
var uniq_ws_data = [
[0:"Hello", 1:"World", 3: "Wow", 4:"I WANT MORE"],
[0:"Meow", 1:"World", 3: "Wow", 4:"MORE I WANT"],
];
```

Comment: Your array syntax is incorrect. WFM with the syntax corrected.

Comment: @jannis what do you mean by that? Can you please elaborate I'm kind of a newbie with this :) . Thanks.

Comment: is: `[[0:"Hello", 1:"World", 3: "Wow", 4:"I WANT MORE"],(...)]`. (Probably) should be `[{0:"Hello", 1:"World", 3: "Wow", 4:"I WANT MORE"},(...)]`

Comment: you might also have this in mind (array of arrays): `["Hello", "World", "Wow", "I WANT MORE"],(...)]`

Comment: Noted @jannis thanks for clearing this up. Will try to follow the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how you managed to run this code, but it is syntactically incorrect. I'm assuming you wanted `initialArray` to be an array of arrays.

Working example:

```js
const initialArray = [
  ["Hello", "World", "Wow", "I WANT MORE"],
  ["Hello", "World", "Wow", "MORE I WANT"],
  ["Meow", "World", "Wow", "MORE I WANT"],
  ["Meow", "World", "Wow", "I WANT MORE"]
];

const result = _.uniqBy(initialArray, _.first);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```